# Read a csv to dictionary with particular column value as key

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to read a csv into a dictionary in python

```
Name    Value    time  count
sample  A        00:00  45
sample  A        01:00  46
sample  A        02:00  50
sample  A        03:00  85
sample  A        04:00  87
abb     B        00:00  40
abb     B        01:00  55
```

I want the output to be :

```
{ A:[{time:00:00 ,count:45},{time:01:00,count:46},{time:02:00,count:50}]}
```

can someone help me how to get the output ?

I tried with dict comprehension I am able to read the csv to a dictionary with key as the column headers and value as the row but not sure how to get the above output.

Comment: You could add your code, so we know where to best advise. Your "wanted" output is not a valid python dict, I guess - but you should state - that the "times" will be strings, as the keys, thus as literal you want: `{'A':[{'time': '00:00', 'count': 45 ...]}` so grouped by 'Value' values, list of dicts for time and count ignoring the "Name" columns values. Please edit the question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

read in file then split to abstract key and value

```
with open(file,'rb') as f:
 res = {}
 reader  = csv.reader(f)
 for i,line in enumerate(reader):
   if i == 0: continue 
   keyWord = line.split(' ')[1]
   timeKeyword  = 'time:' + line.split(' ')[2]
   countValue = line.split(' ')[3]
   res[keyWord ] = res.get(keyWord,[]) + [{timeKeyword : int(countValue )}]
```